# How to get the snapshot of code with an commit number but forget the branch after merges?

Tags: git, merge

We are maintain an code base using git. But have following branchs:

1. master
2. release_branch_1
3. release_branch_2

we regularly merge those three branchs. But after an year we need to investigate an bug, we can find the git change number  `941504fd85b0fede0675b1e934df1aa4763a0390`.

But seams all three branch contains this change, and we forget which branch we build the binary from.

So is it possible to get the snapshot of the code at that time point? Is the `{commit number}` unique identity the snapshot or `{branch + commit number}` pair unique identify the sanpshot?

Comment: Is 941504fd85b0f a commit id? If yes, a simple git checkout 941504fd85b0f would be enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the `{commit number}` unique identity the snapshot or `{branch + commit number}` pair unique identify the snapshot?

2016: The former: to get a snapshot at that commit number, simply [checkout](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) your repo at that commit:

```
git checkout 941504fd85b0fede0675b1e934df1aa4763a0390
```

Branches can evolve, being renamed or deleted, but the commits are immutable.

---

If your bug investigation leads you to make some commit, it is best to checkout that commit with an associated branch, as [hlovdal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23118/hlovdal) comments [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38607270/how-to-get-the-snapshot-of-code-with-an-commit-number-but-forget-the-branch-afte/38607406?noredirect=1#comment64667833_38607406):

```
git checkout -b my_snapshot 941504fd85b0fede0675b1e934df1aa4763a0390
```

Or, if you already checked out the commit directly (and are in a detached HEAD):

```
git branch my_snapshot 941504fd85b0fede0675b1e934df1aa4763a0390
```

---

Note: the right command nowadays (since 2019) would be [`git restore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore)

As its name suggests, `git restore`... *restores* files (in the working tree and/or the index), and opposed to [`git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch), which switches branches. (While the old `git checkout` can do both and is therefore confusing)

In your case, for restoring a snapshot content... `git restore`:

```
git restore --source=941504fd85b0fede0675b1e934df1aa4763a0390 --staged --worktree -- .
```

Or, abbreviated form:

```
git restore -s 941504fd -SW -- .
```

For creating and switching to a new branch... `git switch`:

```
git switch -c my_snapshot 941504fd85b0fede0675b1e934df1aa4763a0390
```

Comment: So any documents to explain how git works when merge changes? I thought the "commit number" just unique identify an diff not an snapshot.

Comment: @ZijingWu Mainly https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging

Comment: And since branches have zero cost in git, might just as well attach one with `git branch my_snapshot 941504fd85b0fede0675b1e934df1aa4763a0390`.

Comment: @hlovdal I agree, and I have edited the answer to reflect the branch creation.